# EMERGENCY - unable to login to Admin panel; also - no users listed in database

Tags: admin-panel, user, admin-user

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I have had a problem twice before where I could not log into the Magento Admin panel with my user name and password. I had to use code in the mySQL to change the password for my Admin user account.

This actually started a couple of hours ago. We have 3 Active accounts:

1 (mine) with the Admin privileges 
and
2 with a specific defined User roles.

The 2 accounts with specific defined User roles lost access first; then I went to the User's area in the Admin panel and found that those 2 accounts were set to DISABLED instead of Enabled. I created a new user account so that I could give it to the other 2 people but shortly after I did that - I was logged off from the Admin panel and was never able to log back in. The new user account I created does NOT work either.

```
I tried to run the following command in the SQL tab of the correct database via mySQL:
```

> UPDATE mg_admin_user SET `password` = md5('test'), is_active = 1 WHERE
>   `username` = 'Allysin'

but it just says that **it took something like 0.003 seconds and there were no rows to update.**

The interesting things is that when I open up the rows of the database and look at:

mg_admin_role

It actually has all the roles I defined before in it!

But when I open up the 'mg_admin_user' --) it is empty.

*What do you think happened? Did somebody hack us and deleted all the user accounts?*

**How can I fix it? Is there a way to add a user account back into the database? Or is there something else I'm missing?**

Answer (score 0):

If the database is still intact & your familiar with using the command line, I'd try using n98-magerun:

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

download it, then just use the `admin:user:create` feature, that'll at least get you back into the system.

Comment: Thank you for that. I do have shell access but this seems a bit complicated...How does one install it? Just copy the file over via FTP and then how do you call up the admin:user:create feature?

Comment: @Allysin - you download the file to your Magento docroot, use chmod +x [filename] and then you should be able to run ./n98-magerun.phar list and it will give you all the available commands, including admin:user:create, you can also run ./n98-magerun admin:user:create --help for an explanation of the command.